# Delete and Update in same time in mssql

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, command, sql-delete, sql-job

I have a job on mssql server for deleting.But my wish is that update another table before deleting.
I have two table which is connected by "user_id" column and my tables names are "UserInfo" and "AdvertInfo", they are connected with user_id column. I am deleting giving_advert_day after 7 days. But when it is deleted , ı would like to increase (+1) user_advert_number column. if delete in user_id, deleted 3 or 4 or etc. data from table then connected data from them will increase +3, +4 or etch. Is there a way for this?
Here is my delete command

```
Delete from AdvertInfo where advert_id In (
select advert_id from AdvertInfo
 where advert_begin_date <  DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Have you looked at triggers?

Comment: You can use a trigger in this table to delete automatically after the update.

Comment: I have no information about trigger so ı couldnt do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `UPDATE` with `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE u
SET u.user_advert_number = u.user_advert_number + 1
FROM UserInfo as u
INNER JOIN AdvertInfo AS a ON u.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE a.advert_begin_date <  DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()))
```

BTW, your delete clause can be written as following:

```
Delete 
from AdvertInfo 
where advert_begin_date <  DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()))
```

There is no need for the `IN` predicate.

---

You can also create an [create a trigger](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799(v=sql.105).aspx), to executed `after delete` for example to update the column the way you want.

Comment: thank you so much. bu it will be same time in sql server agent job? and it has to update delete times in advert.

Comment: @KAYA - Yes you can use it in a job with now problem,and you can use both the queries after each others, but the trigger will be preferred in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use  the query below to achieve that you want:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (
    [user_id] INT
)

DELETE i
OUTPUT deleted.[user_id] INTO @Temp
FROM AdvertInfo i
WHERE advert_begin_date <  DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())

UPDATE u
SET u.user_advert_number = u.user_advert_number + d.cnt
FROM UserInfo as u
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [user_id], COUNT([user_id]) AS cnt
        FROM @Temp
        GROUP BY [user_id]
    ) d ON d.[user_id] = u.[user_id]
```

Answer (score 1):

Merhaba Kaya,
Maybe you can use [SQL OUTPUT clause](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/insert-into-two-tables-using-t-sql-output-clause.aspx) as follows
You may already know, while executing DELETE command you can get affected data with OUTPUT clause into a variable table and as you can see in following sample you can use it later

```
DECLARE @Deleted table (  
    user_id int
);  

DELETE FROM AdvertInfo
OUTPUT DELETED.user_id
INTO @Deleted 
WHERE advert_begin_date <  DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())

update u
set user_advert_number = isnull(user_advert_number,0) + 1
from UserInfo as u
inner join @Deleted d on d.user_id = u.user_id
```